# windows 7 docker virtual-box connecting issue

Tags: docker, virtualbox

Im trying to get docker toolbox working on windows 7.

I have the VM starting and able to shh into it.

but when i do a `docker run hello-world` i get

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup https on 192.168.0.1:53: no such host.
```

I have tried pinging the VM as well and there is no response in the windows pc.

Answer (score 0):

What does 'docker-machine env' says? Check if it's the same ip(192.168.0.1:53) as in config.json